# Read a whole std::istream into a std::string or std::vector<char>

Tags: c++11, stl, stream, containers

I would like to read a whole binary stream into a std::string or a std::vector until EOF is reached.

I have tried

```
std::vector<char> compressed(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), {});
```

But it only read 247 bytes out of 255kB, I suppose it stopped at a null byte.

Is there another option than reading in a loop until !stream.good() ?

Thanks!

Comment: The "end" `istreambut_iterator` is a default-constructed instance, like `std::istreambuf_iterator{}`. Start by using that.

Comment: `std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(vec));`

Comment: Use: `std::vector<char> compressed((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));` to read every byte into the vector. The parentheses are there to avoid the "most vexing parse".

Comment: Have you, by any chance, opened the file in text mode, on Windows, containing `'\x1A'` byte? This character is treated as EOF indicator, for compatibility with DOS. Make sure to open the file in binary mode.